# Assign event listener to dynamically created TPanel in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I created a `TPanel` component like this:

```
procedure TVistaVehiculo.CrearMenu(Name: string);
var
  Panel : TPanel;
begin
  Panel := TPanel.Create(VistaVehiculo);
  Panel.Parent := VistaVehiculo.Sidebar;
  Panel.Width := VistaVehiculo.Sidebar.Width;
  Panel.Height := 40;
  Panel.Caption := Name;
  Panel.BevelInner := TBevelCut.bvNone;
  Panel.BevelOuter := TBevelCut.bvNone;
  Panel.BevelKind := TBevelKind.bkNone;
end;
```

Now, I want to attach an event listener to this panel and pass the object as a parameter.

So then I create a procedure like this:

```
procedure TVistaVehiculo.ClickOnMenu(Sender: TPanel);
begin
    Sender.Caption := 'Clicked'; //for example
end;
```

How can I do this?

Sorry if the question is dumb - I'm pretty new to Delphi

Comment: `Panel.OnClick := Self.ClickOnMenu;` Note that `Self` is the actual instance of `TVistaVehiculo`. The use of `VistaVehiculo` is not the way to refer to the form instance. Avoid that.

Comment: It should be noted that he'll need to alter his ClickOnMenu declaration to `ClickOnMenu(Sender : TObject)`, since OnClick is a TNotificationEvent.

Comment: @KenBourassa, good catch, missed that.

Comment: Related, but not necessarily a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28265513/setting-the-onclick-procedure-of-a-delphi-button-at-runtime/28265603#28265603

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
procedure TVistaVehiculo.CrearMenu(Name: string);
var
  Panel : TPanel;
begin
  Panel := TPanel.Create(VistaVehiculo);
  Panel.Parent := VistaVehiculo.Sidebar;
  Panel.Width := VistaVehiculo.Sidebar.Width;
  Panel.Height := 40;
  Panel.Caption := Name;
  Panel.BevelInner := TBevelCut.bvNone;
  Panel.BevelOuter := TBevelCut.bvNone;
  Panel.BevelKind := TBevelKind.bkNone;
  Panel.OnClick := ClickOnMenu; // <-- add this!
end;

procedure TVistaVehiculo.ClickOnMenu(Sender: TObject); // <-- must be TObject!
begin
  TPanel(Sender).Caption := 'Clicked';
end;
```