# Delphi pass object as parameter on click event

Tags: delphi

I have this code:

```
for LSidebarButton in SidebarButtons do
  begin
    LSidebarOverlay := TPanel(LSidebarButton.Button.Controls[3]);
    LSidebarOverlay.OnClick := SetSidebarButtonActive(nil, LSidebarButton);
  end;
```

And then I have a procedure

```
procedure SetSidebarButtonActive(sender: TObject; btn: TSidebarButton);
begin
    btn.SetActive;
    //more code
end;
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
E2010 Incompatible types: 'TNotifyEvent' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped parameter'
```

Comment: The VCL code calls the event handler. It decides the interface. The method has a single argument. You don't get to change that. I'm sure there is a solution to your problem. This isn't it. What the solution is depends on what the problem is. We can't see the problem.

Comment: Additionally you can't call a method while assigning to a procedural type at the same time. What will eventually compile is "LSidebarOverlay.OnClick := SetSidebarButtonActive;" after you correct the signature of RHS.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan so there's absolutely no way to workaround this? The problem is the following. The class TSidebarButton has a Button element which has a Panel inside. When I click that Panel I want to set that object (instance of the class) active property to "true" and call a method on it, and loop through the list of SidebarButtons to set all the properties to "false".

Comment: There will be a solution. But you have to ask the right question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting the OnClick procedure of a Delphi button at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28265513/setting-the-onclick-procedure-of-a-delphi-button-at-runtime)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because you are trying to *call* `SetSidebarButtonActive()` and then assign its result (which it has none) to the `OnClick` event.  That will not work.

The `OnClick` event is defined as a [`TNotifyEvent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TNotifyEvent):

```
TNotifyEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject) of object;
```

That means that

- the procedure needs to be a member of a class
- you have to assign the *address* of the procedure to `OnClick`, not *call* the procedure
- the procedure *must* take only 1 input parameter, which is the `TObject` that fires the event (in this case, the `TPanel` that is being clicked on).

So, for what you are attempting, you would need to do something more like this instead:

```
procedure TMyForm.DoSomething;
var
  ...
  LSidebarButton: TSidebarButton;
  LSidebarOverlay: TPanel;
  ...
begin
  ...
  for LSidebarButton in SidebarButtons do
  begin
    LSidebarOverlay := TPanel(LSidebarButton.Button.Controls[3]);
    LSidebarOverlay.OnClick := SetSidebarButtonActive;
  end;
  ...
end;

procedure TMyForm.SetSidebarButtonActive(Sender: TObject);
var
  Pnl: TPanel;
  Btn: TSidebarButton;
begin
  Pnl := TPanel(Sender);

  Btn := (Pnl.Parent as TSidebarButton);
  // or maybe (Pnl.Parent.Parent as TSidebarButton)?
  // or maybe (Pnl.Owner as TSidebarButton)?
  // or maybe (Pnl.Parent.Owner as TSidebarButton)?
  // Hard to know with your example. Use whatever you
  // need to get back to the TSidebarButton from its
  // inner child TPanel...

  Btn.SetActive;
  ...
end;
```

Alternatively, you can store the `TSidebarButton` reference in the `TPanel.Tag` property (assuming you are not using it for something else):

```
procedure TMyForm.DoSomething;
var
  ...
  LSidebarButton: TSidebarButton;
  LSidebarOverlay: TPanel;
  ...
begin
  ...
  for LSidebarButton in SidebarButtons do
  begin
    LSidebarOverlay := TPanel(LSidebarButton.Button.Controls[3]);
    LSidebarOverlay.Tag := NativeInt(LSidebarButton);
    LSidebarOverlay.OnClick := SetSidebarButtonActive;
  end;
  ...
end;

procedure TMyForm.SetSidebarButtonActive(Sender: TObject);
var
  Btn: TSidebarButton;
begin
  Btn := TSidebarButton(TPanel(Sender).Tag);
  Btn.SetActive;
  ...
end;
```

Alternatively, you can define a helper class to provide you access to the `TSidebarButton` without looking at the `TPanel` at all:

```
type
  TOverlayClickHelper = class(TComponent)
  public
    Button: TSidebarButton;
    procedure OnClick(Sender: TObject);
  end;

...

procedure SetSidebarButtonActive(Btn: TSidebarButton);
begin
  Btn.SetActive;
  //more code
end;

procedure TOverlayClickHelper.OnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetSidebarButtonActive(Button);
end;

procedure TMyForm.DoSomething;
var
  ...
  LSidebarButton: TSidebarButton;
  LSidebarOverlay: TPanel;
  Helper: TOverlayClickHelper;
  ...
begin
  ...
  for LSidebarButton in SidebarButtons do
  begin
    LSidebarOverlay := TPanel(LSidebarButton.Button.Controls[3]);
    Helper := TOverlayClickHelper(LSidebarOverlay.FindComponent('MyHelper'));
    if Helper = nil then
    begin
      Helper := TOverlayClickHelper.Create(LSidebarOverlay);
      Helper.Name := 'MyHelper';
    end;
    Helper.Button := LSidebarButton;
    LSidebarOverlay.OnClick := Helper.OnClick;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Alternatively, if you are creating the `TPanel` objects yourself inside of `TSidebarButton`, you could simply derive a new class from `TPanel` to add a `TSidebarButton` reference to it:

```
type
  TSidebarButtonPanel = class(TPanel)
  public
    Button: TSidebarButton;
  end;

...

procedure TSidebarButton.CreateOverlay;
var
  LOverlay: TSidebarButtonPanel;
begin
  LOverlay := TSidebarButtonPanel.Create(Self);
  LOverlay.Parent := Self.Button;
  LOverlay.Button := Self;
  ...
end;

...

procedure TMyForm.DoSomething;
var
  ...
  LSidebarButton: TSidebarButton;
  LSidebarOverlay: TPanel;
  ...
begin
  ...
  for LSidebarButton in SidebarButtons do
  begin
    LSidebarOverlay := TPanel(LSidebarButton.Button.Controls[3]);
    LSidebarOverlay.OnClick := SetSidebarButtonActive;
  end;
  ...
end;

procedure TMyForm.SetSidebarButtonActive(Sender: TObject);
var
  Btn: TSidebarButton;
begin
  Btn := TSidebarButtonPanel(Sender).Button;
  Btn.SetActive;
  ...
end;
```

There are all kinds of options available to you.

Comment: The problem is the TSidebarButton is a  custom class I made, and the sender panel is a control from a control inside the TSidebarButton class.

So, I can't get the object reference from the TPanel control (the sender)  :/

Comment: Yes, you can, and I even showed you how to do that (walk the panel's `Parent`/`Owner` hierarchy.until you reach the `TSidebarButton`).  You control the relationship between Button and Panel, so use whatever it takes to get back to the Button from the Panel. That being said, I have updated my answer to include some alternative solutions.